# for i = 1 skips a few spots

Tags: excel, vba

I have a for loop that works but when i check the results there are some rows that got skipped.

Is there something that sticks out to anyone that could be the result of the loop not seeing every #.

It always seems to skip on the same row containing the digit 3 and one containing the digit 6. I will run other rows correctly with those same digits.

It should see a row containing "3 SHEETS" for example and copy that row and insert 2 rows below it and paste. So there are 3 duplicate rows that I end up renaming to `Descriptions (SHEET 1)` etc.

In my spreadsheet it runs on integers 2, 4, 3 (Then skips 2) runs on 13 (Then skips 3) and runs on 7 in that order, if that helps any.  I have another macro that does some renaming and that hits all the "Sheets" words so I know its not a problem with an extra space or something.

```
Sub ExpandRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Drawing Index")

With ws
For i = 1 To 99
    Set aCell = .Columns(1).find(What:=i & " SHEETS", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        aCell.EntireRow.Copy
        aCell.Resize(i - 1).Insert
    End If
Next
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You're changing content during the loop with `.Insert`. Don't do that, because it throws your counter off. If you **must** alter it, then reverse your loop and go from 99 down to 1.

Comment: You are only doing your `Insert` at most once per loop, so once for `"1 SHEETS"`, once for `"2 SHEETS"`, once for `"3 SHEETS"`, etc.  If you have two occurrences of `"3 SHEETS"` it will only process one of them.

Comment: Note also that, in one of your previous questions, it was suggested by @BruceWayne that you should search for `"(" & i & " SHEETS)"`.  If you don't, you are going to end up inserting 14 rows when you have `"(13 SHEETS)"`, i.e. 2 rows when it is processing `"3 SHEETS"` and another 12 rows when it is processing `"13 SHEETS"`.

Comment: @YowE3K How can i have it process all matching integers and not just the first matched integer then pass to the next one? There will be many times that i will have multiple 2 or 3 Sheet cells. I dont want to do just the first i would like to do all.

Comment: In your current structure you would need to have, within your `For i = 1 To 99` loo[, another loop for the `Find`.  (If I was doing this, my approach would be to simply go through row by row, see if column A contained `" SHEETS)"`, if so I would parse out the number and insert the desired rows, then go to the next row and repeat the process.  But I tend to use old-school approaches to things, so that may not be the best thing for you.)

Comment: I see you re-asked this same question, and @Jeeped provided an answer which pretty much would be what I would do but, without the knowledge of your data, his "parse out the number" part didn't work.  I recommend you use his code and just update the bit extracting the number from the "description".