# search cell for string then run macro if string is found

Tags: vba, excel

Right now my macro runs but doesn't get all the numbers. If it ran once on #2 then the next #2 gets skipped. How can i prevent this. I want all #'s to get processed.

*Example:*
HI (2 SHEETS)
OK (3 SHEETS)
BYE (2 SHEETS)

*should be:*
HI (2 SHEETS)
HI (2 SHEETS)
OK (3 SHEETS)
OK (3 SHEETS)
OK (3 SHEETS)
BYE (2 SHEETS)
BYE (2 SHEETS)

This is what i have so far.

**OLD**

```
Sub ExpandRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Drawing Index")

With ws
For i = 2 To 99
    Set aCell = .Columns(1).find(What:="(" & i & " SHEETS)", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        aCell.EntireRow.Copy
        aCell.Resize(i - 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = "Duplicating rows containing (" & i & " SHEETS)..."
Next i
End With        
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

I've been told that its probably skipping the other matches because of the `insert` of new rows. How can i get around this? Is there another way.

**EDIT_7.25.17**
I am trying to get this code to run if a cell contains the text "SHEETS". I have tried a bunch of things and im stuck.

```
Sub ExpandRows_if()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet, l As Long, n As Long, s As Long, tmp As String, rng As range, SearchChar As String
Dim LastRow As Long, aCell As range
LastRow = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = range("A3:A" & LastRow)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Drawing Index")
SearchChar = "SHEETS"

With ws
For Each aCell In rng.Cells '(x)
    'If aCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Countifs(rng.value,""*SHEETS)*""),1,0)" > 0 Then '(x)_This works as a formula on the sheet
    If InStr(1, aCell, SearchChar, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then '(x)_Other option i am trying
        For l = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            s = InStr(1, .Cells(l, "A").Value2, "(")
            If CBool(s) Then
                n = val(Mid(.Cells(l, "A").Value2, s + 1))
                If n > 0 Then
                    .Cells(l + 1, "A").Resize(n-1).EntireRow.Insert
                    .Cells(1, "A").Resize(n + 1, 1).EntireRow.FillDown
                    Application.StatusBar = "Duplicating rows containing (" & n & " SHEETS)"
                End If
            End If
        Next l
    Else '(x)
        MsgBox "Damn! Still not working", vbOKOnly, "F*@&" '(x)
    Exit Sub '(x)
    End If '(x)
Next '(x)
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
End Sub
```

`'(x)` Indicates the new lines I added to get the IF statement working. Without these the code works but duplicates all rows. Well it should duplicate but the `.FillDown` doesn't seem to be working. ATM it is inserting the correct amount of rows.

Thanks

Comment: It isn't skipping the other matches due to the `Insert` of new rows.  As I explained in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45228118/6535336), you are only attempting to process the first match for each value of `i`.  And you are also potentially creating 14 rows when processing `"13 SHEETS)" because you have possible already inserted 2 rows when `"13 SHEETS)"` was matched against a search for `"3 SHEETS)"`.

Comment: @YowE3K I am not getting that a problem when i have 3 sheets and 13 sheets and vice versa. Both ways add the appropriate amount of new rows. only problem is that the loop runs a digit once. if i have a sequence of 2,3,4,3 then the 2,3,4 will run but since the 3 ran already then the last 3 will not activate. im not sure how i can get the loop to run 20 times for 2, then 3...

Comment: @Jeeped answer would be the way to get it to run multiple times for 2, then 3, etc.  But you need to provide more info if you want someone else to show you how to parse the number out of the description.  Without that info, you will need to do the parsing code yourself.

Comment: @YowE3K just tried that sequence. I get 13 total rows

Comment: Ahhh - my apologies - I hadn't noticed that this version of the code added in BruceWayne's suggestion of putting the opening `"("`.  That will teach me to not assume the code was the same as the last time.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble with iterating the cells of `rng` is that, as you insert new rows, `rng` expands, which messes up your sequence. One should never iterate over a collection that is affected by the very iterating statements.

A more primitive approach, with pointer variables and a conditional loop, however, allow you to regain control of where you are in the worksheet.

Since I noticed your sample range starts on **"A3"** cell, I'd rather explicitly define a starting row (in variable `FirstRow`, so you can either parametrize your statement, or at least edit it in a tidy, self-explaining point, instead of delving down to more intrincate parts of your code.

As for tidiness, I also changed the fashion of `Dim` statements, for better readability.

So, this should do it (it worked on my tests):

```
Sub ExpandRows_if()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    Dim s As Long
    Dim e As Long
    Dim l As Long
    Dim nl As Long
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim SearchChar As String
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FirstRow = 1
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Drawing Index")
    SearchChar = "SHEETS"

    With ws
        l = FirstRow
        Do
            Set aCell = .Cells(l, 1)
            If InStr(1, aCell, SearchChar, vbTextCompare) > 0 And _
               InStr(1, aCell, "(", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                s = InStr(1, aCell, "(", vbTextCompare)
                e = InStr(s, aCell, " ", vbTextCompare)
                n = Mid(aCell.Value, s + 1, e - s - 1)
                If n > 1 Then
                    Application.StatusBar = "Duplicating rows containing (" & n & " SHEETS)"
                    For nl = 1 To n - 1
                        aCell.Offset(nl, 0).EntireRow.Insert
                        aCell.Offset(nl, 0).Value = aCell.Value
                        LastRow = LastRow + 1 ' Since a row was inserted, last and
                        l = l + 1             ' current line pointers must increase by 1
                    Next
                End If
            End If
            l = l + 1 ' step to new line
        Loop While l <= LastRow
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
End Sub
```

Comment: How can i get it to copy the first 2 columns?

Comment: `Dim aCell2 as Range` (...) `Set aCell2 = .Cells(l, 2)` (...) `aCell2.Offset(nl, 0).Value = aCell2.Value`. I leave to you to find out where to insert those statements ;-)

Comment: Thank you sir, works like a charm! Will award the bounty once it lets me. it says 20hrs